# jQuery script being rendered instead of executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a legacy application I'm working, somehow the jQuery scripts between

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

are being rendered as plain text instead of being executed.

Does someone have a suggestion of what can cause this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery scripts"?

Comment: where's the rest of your code, and the further details on what you're running it in, and how you're serving the code? Just that script element will, in any browser, run the code that's in it so right now your question has nothing in it that's actually verifiably broken.

Comment: Do the `<script>` tags have `display: block`?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  What does that script tag look like when you view source in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using something like style : `{display:block}` it will behave like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can not see all your code I will give you a few possible causes.
1.you could have forgot a closing tag for an element above it.
2.You could have forgot a pair of parenthesis on an element above.
3.You might have put the tag in a wrong spot so it might print depending on it's position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable css. If it works fine after it, then you've styled tag 'script'.

Answer (score -1):

Remember to read [how to ask a question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

But based on the little information given i'll make a longshot and think it might be something with parsing, read about [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

And [check for unclosed html tags](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html).